# What does the role of the "ko.validation.rules.pattern.message" instruction?

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I finally found out how to use knockout validation, but I still not get the reason for the initialization:

`ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';
ko.validation.init({
    // some cfg. here. For example: 
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null
}, true);`

But what is the reason of the first line above? May I change it to something else?
For example:

```
ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Error.';
```

Which is the result of the changement and what happen if I do not use it al all?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.'
```

will display `'Invalid'` as error message whenever the input value is not matched with pattern you specified for field. You can change the message to anything you want. But note that, this is a global override for `pattern.message`. You should probably use extend to specify error messages for each observable.

```
var name = ko.observable().extend({
                     minLength: 3,
                     pattern: {
                          message: 'Pattern for name not matched.',
                          params: '^[A-Z0-9].$'
                     }
                 });


var phoneNumber = ko.observable().
            .extend({ pattern: {
                 message: 'The phone number is not in correct format.',
                 params: '^[A-Z0-9].$'
            }});
```